# How to find tables processed by VACCUM(FULL, ANALYZE) but not VERBOSE

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

So I have cancelled a global VACUUM FULL out of necessity, there will be tables that were not processed and can now be individually targeted.

Problem. VACUUM(FULL, ANALYZE) does not update last_vacuum, a known issue for a decade?

How can I identify the tables that were completed, so that I might by extension identify the complement of those?  I cannot find a duplicate of this, but I find it hard to believe this is the first time the question has been asked. I am aware that this could have been extracted from verbose output.

Comment: NB. Whist this was fresh, last_analyze has been deemed good enough to get me by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VACUUM (FULL)` isn't really `VACUUM`, strange as that seems. Rather, it is `CLUSTER` without a special ordering. The reason for this oddity is partly that the implementation of `VACUUM (FULL)` was radically changed in version 9.0. Since it is so different from normal `VACUUM`, it is not tracked in `pg_stat_user_tables.last_vacuum`, and its progress is tracked in `pg_stat_progress_cluster` rather than in `pg_stat_progress_vacuum`.

Apart from `pg_stat_user_tables.last_analyze`, which you can use since you ran `VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE)`, you could look at the creation timestamp of the data files. That would work, since `VACUUM (FULL)` creates a new copy of the table.

On Windows, you can use the following query for that:

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass,
       s.creation
FROM pg_class AS t
   JOIN pg_database AS d ON d.datname = current_database()
   JOIN pg_tablespace AS ts
      ON CASE WHEN t.reltablespace = 0 THEN d.dattablespace
              ELSE t.reltablespace
         END = ts.oid
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL pg_stat_file(
                         CASE ts.spcname
                            WHEN 'pg_default' THEN 'base/' || d.oid
                            WHEN 'pg_global' THEN 'global'
                            ELSE 'pg_tblspc/' || ts.oid || '/' || d.oid
                         END
                         || '/' || pg_relation_filenode(t.oid::regclass)
                      ) AS s
WHERE t.relkind = 'r'
ORDER BY s.creation;
```

On other operating systems, `pg_stat_file()` returns NULL for `creation`, and you'd have to go look into the file system yourself.

Comment: Thank you, sadly as it is a managed instance I do not have access to the file system. This is a good historical explanation too.